# Comparing two strings for similarity in PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison, matching, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to find the best solution for comparing two similar strings and choosing the most similar it can find.

I have an array of straight movie names. I also have an array of movie names with additional text.

Example:

My straight movie name array contains strings like so:

```
"Super Troopers", 
"Everest", 
"Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace"
```

My other array with movie strings are in forms similar to the following:

```
"Super Troopers (2001) 720P-AC3-x264", 
"Everest - 2015.1080p.DTS mkv", 
"Star Wars - Episode 1: The Phantom Menace 1080p h265 HEVC TrueHD"
```

What I'm currently doing is looping through my first array comparing each movie with the second array and using `strpos()` If I find an exact match, great. If not I need to perform some other function to look for which two strings are most similar. I have tried using `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()` with mixed results.

In my above examples, `strpos()` would have matched both Everest and Super Troopers just fine, but for the Star Wars string I need additional checks. Things like hyphens and colons and "I" and "1" used differently along with the additional information that follows the movie name seem to give me sporadic results with `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()`

I'm thinking of maybe first substring out the movie names with the additional information by first calculating the `strlen()` of the movie name plus 5 or so additional characters for good measure before running a `similar_text()` or `levenshtein()` function/s, since the one common thing they all have is their movie names are at the start of the string. This could make the string similarity functions maybe a bit more accurate?

Or maybe some function that breaks up each word and checks to see how many match in the other string. Does such a function exist?

I'll mess around with it more, but if anyone has any input on how they might tackle the problem, I'd love to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the goal to find the one record in the second list which most closely matches each result in the first list? Is each of the movies in the first list guaranteed to appear exactly once in the second list? How long are the two lists? Is the entry in the second list guaranteed to contain all of the **words** in the entry in the first list, or are there cases where this doesn't happen?

Comment: Yes, the first list also contains other array data such as IMDBs link that I want to add to the second list once we have the correct match. The lists are anywhere between 10-50 movies. No it's not guaranteed all the words will match exactly "The Choice" might be a movie in the first list with "Choice 2016 DTS x264 etc etc" in the second list ("The" being the missing word). Right now using `substr($secondListMovie, 0, strlen($firstListMovie))` before using similar_text or levenshtein is giving me much better matches since the movie names in the second list all begin at the start of the string

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of two complete lists?

Comment: Sure, here is an example of the [first list](http://pastebin.com/qufBg0Rk). And here is an example of the [second list](http://pastebin.com/YkbhH4iz). They are in JSON format at the output, but are in normal PHP array format in code.

Comment: Quite a lot of films are in the first list but not in the second at all. For example, Krampus. What is the desired behaviour in this case?

Comment: Right, this does happen, in which case if the similarity tolerance is too low (the movie likely wasn't in both lists), then I just leave the IMDB fields blank for that release. I can get around this issue and the entire main issue as a whole, but making a separate cURL request for each individual movie in the first list to grab the additional IMDB data that I want to add to the first. I would not have to do any sort of string searching then, but I'd be hitting the particular site with a lot more cURL requests all at once.

Comment: I don't really have a decent solution. In fact, I don't really think it's possible to come up with anything that doesn't sometimes return the wrong match for a film which isn't in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for an interesting solution. It uses a database. Every time you get a new Movie in your collection, you separate the movie name into words. For instance:

```
"Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace"
```

would be separated into:

```
"Star", "Wars:", "Episode", "I", "The", "Phantom", "Menace"
```

From there, you would have the following tables in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_search (
movie_keyword varchar(255) NOT NULL,
movie_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (movie_keyword)
)

CREATE TABLE movies (
movie_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
movie_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)
)
```

Example of the movie_search table:

```
key_word | movie_id
star -------- 1
wars -------- 1
spider ------ 2
man --------- 2
```

Example of the movies table:

```
movie_id | movie_name
1 -------- star wars
2 -------- spider man
```

Every time someone wants to search for a movie in your website, you would break their phrase into all the words using `explode(" ", $searched_name);`. From there you would search in your database all the matching key_word matchs in the movie_search table, and if the movie_id repeated, you would be able to increase the count of keyword matches you found for each movie. So after having done a search with some good PHP behind it, your result should be a multidimentional array with 3 elements in each row:

```
array (
  [0] => array (
    [movie_id] = 1,
    [movie_name] = star wars,
    [count] = 2),
  [1] => array (...),
    ....
)
```

where the movie with the most keywords (highest count) would appear at the top of your array. You can also decide how many results you want to output by placing "ORDER BY 10" in your SQL code

HOPE THAT HELPS! :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't really want to be using a database as I'm not using it as a search engine. Basically I'm combining other array data from each array that contains those strings such as IMDB URL and such. My idea of using substring first of the length of the movie name to compare is working a lot better than my previous attempts.